# Command line export and import CSV in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv

I have a database `xyz` and 100+ tables and has to perform the following operations on the command line:

1. I need to create CSV of all tables in one go.
2. CSV with column separator `,`, fields enclosed by `" "` and lines terminated by `\n`.
3. Restore the all created CSV in one go.

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about importing/exporting the *contents* of the tables, right?

Comment: yes..records of table.

Comment: Okay. Which methods have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried SQLCMD and BCP. But unable to pick fields enclosed by "". I can create the txt flat files enclosed by "" with the help of Import and Export tool using text delimiter, but this has to do one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your need, I can suggest couple of options :

- Use SSIS Import/Export; or
- Use BCP OUT and BCP IN

Each method has its own benefits and it all depends on your requirement which one to choose.

Comment: Using SSIS Import/Export is good to generate CSV but I need to create all csvs in one sort and fields enclosed by "".Even BCP has no any option to fields enclosed by "".

Comment: Can I ask -- what are your trying to achieve by creating CSV's for entire database ? Are you trying to generate csvs per table ?
Let us know as your requirement is vague to me ...

Comment: trying to generate CSVs per table. My main concern is to generate CSVs that has fields enclosed by " ".